# Is it possible to get position in 2D scene WITHOUT script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have placed a png background to my game, and i would like to know the position of certain element in the background (the top on the tree, i have pointed with red arrow)
I would like to know the 2D position of this tree top. I want to click with mouse on the tree top and get the position.
I don't want to use script.
I need to know a lot of locations in the background and i want to get them while the game is not played, but rather when i am in editor mode in the scene view, as shown in the picture.
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple. Click the `+` in the top left of the Hierarchy, and add an `Empty GameObject`. Make sure it's Z position is the same as your background, and move it using the handles in the scene to the top of the tree. Once there, look at the position on the right, and that is the position of that point.

Comment: Thank you, i have used this trick up until now, and was hoping for something more built-in

Comment: I believe that is the most built in you can get, and it works fine. The only other thing I could think of is a package that includes such a thing, but I don't know of any.